# Javascript: get username substring(s) beginning with @ symbol

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a good way to get one or more usernames preceded by a `@` symbol in a string.

Some example strings could be:

- "@username this is just a test string"
- "Blabla bla @username this is just a test string"
- "Message for @username1, @username2 and @username_three: this is just a test string! - @username4"

Any solutions? I've not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### One occurrence

To match a single occurrence use a regular expression without any modifier and then get rid of the `@` using `.substr(1)`:

```js
const myString = "Hey @username this is a test string";
const username = myString.match(/@\w+/)[0].substr(1);    
// This will be "username"
```

NOTE: the `\w` in the regular expression is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

### Multiple occurrences

For more than one occurrence use a regular expression with the `g` modifier to match more than one string, then use the `.map()` method to remove the `@` characters at the beginning of each username using `.substr(1)` to throw away the first character:

```js
const myString = "Hey @username1 and @Username_Two, this is just a test string! @username3";
const usernames = myString.match(/@\w+/g).map(x => x.substr(1));
// This will be ["username1", "Username_Two", "username3"]
```

NOTE: I am using the regular expression `/@\w+/g` since that usernames can contain only letters, numbers and underscores (at least on the most common sites, like Twitter etc).

Answer (score 4):

Try regular expression:

```
var m = "@username This is just a test string".match(/@(.+?)\b/);
console.log(m); // ["@username", "username"]
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. What if there was more than 1 username in a string? Thanks.

Comment: @user2957677 - please add this new requirement to your original post. Also you can take a look at this meta post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Answer (score 2):

The other answers work fine <sup><sub>(mostly)</sub></sup>. I'm adding this as an alternative for matching multiple instances of usernames:

```
var str = "random @foo string @bar test @baz";
var usernames = str.split(/@(\w+)/).filter(function(_, i) { return i % 2; });
// [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]
```

This works because if you place a capture group inside the pattern when you call [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), it will include that matched group in the result array. Then you just have to take every other array element.

Note also that [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) was added in ECMAScript 5.1, so it may not be supported in older browsers. If this is a concern, either use the polyfill technique described in the MDN article, or a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score -2):

Just do:

```
var user = "@username";
var user2 = user.split("@")[1];
```

Comment: No - this is not what the OP requested. Take a look at the example input that was given: `"@username This is just a test string"`. Your example is too simplified.